# Why is cut not matching any delimiters?

Tags: bash, sh, cut

The following is not working properly, `cut` is not separating at the dot but `{}` definitely contains a dot in the file name.
`find . -type f -exec echo ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy $(echo {} | cut -d "." -s -f 1).mp4 \;`

Comment: Bash performs command substitution before the command is run, you have to put in single quotes to work.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk like the following? find . -type f -exec 'ffmpeg -i {} -vcodec copy -acodec copy $(echo {} | cut -d "." -s -f 1).mp4' \; ???

Comment: no, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash performs command substitution before the command is run, you have
to put in single quotes to work. The command you want to run is
complex enough to call it with a separate instance of `sh` like that:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo ffmpeg -i "$1" -vcodec copy -acodec copy $(echo "$1" | sed "s,^\./,," | cut -d "." -s -f 1).mp4' sh {} \;
```

For example, if the directory in which you want to run the command
looked like that:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir
│   └── file_something.avi
├── file_a.avi
├── file_b.avi
├── file_c.avi
└── find.sh

1 directory, 5 files
```

it would return:

```
ffmpeg -i ./file_c.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy file_c.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./find.sh -vcodec copy -acodec copy find.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./file_b.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy file_b.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./file_a.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy file_a.mp4
ffmpeg -i ./dir/file_something.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy dir/file_something.mp4
```